# How to view current settings for all options?

Tags: zsh

I know that `setopt` with arguments will show the options that are set *to values different from the default*; e.g.

```
% setopt
interactive
login
monitor
norcs
shinstdin
zle
```

*If* you have memorized all the `zsh` options and their default values, then the information provided by the no-argument form of `setopt` is all you need in order to know the settings of *all* the current `zsh` options.

If you have *not* memorized all the `zsh` options and their default values, a way to explicitly list the current settings of *all* the `zsh` options would be useful.

Comment: `set -o` or `print -aC2 ${(kv)options}`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: That's just the ticket.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As was stated in a comment, run

```bash
set -o
```

or

```bash
print -raC2 -- "${(kv@)options}"
```

> Note: On older versions of Zsh, for the latter to work, you might first need to run `zmodload zsh/parameter`.

Documentation:

- [`set` builtin](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-set)
- [`options` table](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Modules.html#index-options-1)